# Evaluating Dirichlet $L$-functions at $s=1$

Tags: number-theory, closed-form, l-functions

I'm trying to find references on general methods for evaluating Dirichlet $L$-functions at $s=1$, but it's proving a little harder to google than I'd hoped. Specifically I'm looking for any books or papers that go through methods for solving the following question: suppose I have a (possibly primitive) Dirichlet character $\chi$ of conductor $q$, what is the value of $L(1,\chi)$? Any insights anyone has about this that *aren't* a book or paper would also be very much appreciated.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112688/the-value-of-a-dirichlet-l-function-and-its-derivative-at-s-0) has a good amount of detail on how to approach the problem, but it only covers odd characters. The Wikipedia page for the analytic class number formula also has [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula#Dirichlet_class_number_formula), which gives closed forms for $L$-functions at $s=1$, but this is only for primitive characters with prime conductors (and possibly only for quadratic characters?) This is as much as I could find, and as for the more general cases I'm at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For primitive characters $\chi$ mod $m$, odd or even, a formula is given in Prop 3.4.8 of [my Number Theory II notes](http://www.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/ntii/).

If I have a character $\chi$ mod $m$ which is not primitive, but say comes from the primitive character $\chi'$ mod $m'$, then the values  $\chi(p)$ and $\chi'(p)$ are only different if $p | m$ but $p \nmid m'$ (in which case $\chi(p) = 0$).  So by the Euler product, we have
$$
L(s, \chi) = \prod_p (1-\chi(p)p^{-s})^{-1}
= \prod_{p | m, p \nmid m'} (1-\chi'(p)p^{-s}) \times L(s, \chi').
$$

Thus one can use the formula in the primitive case to compute $L(1,\chi')$ and consequently
$$
L(1, \chi) = \prod_{p | m, p \nmid m'} (1-\chi'(p)p^{-1})
L(1,\chi').
$$

Comment: Should the condition on the extra product not be $p\mid m, p\not\mid m'$?

Comment: @ribbcastle I'm confused about your condition---that's the same condition I wrote on the product.

Comment: apologies! the resolution on my screen is not great! I copied down an incorrect version, $p\mid m$, $p\mid m'$, and I guess just stopped being able to see what you'd actually written.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$f(x ) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{\chi(n)}{n} e^{-nx}$$
For $\chi(n)$ a non-trivial Dirichlet character modulo $q$ then 
$$\Gamma(s)L(s+1,\chi) = \int_0^\infty   f(x)x^{s-1}dx$$
converges and is analytic for $\Re(s) > 0$.

$$\Gamma(s)L(s+1,\chi)-f(0) \Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty (f(x)-f(0) e^{-x})x^{s-1}dx$$
converges and is analytic for $\Re(s) > -1$.

Since $\Gamma(s)$ has a pole at $s=0$ it means $$L(1,\chi) = f(0) $$
The discrete Fourier transform gives
$$\chi(n) = \frac{1}{q} \sum_{k=1}^{q} \widehat{\chi}(k) e^{2i \pi nk/q}, \qquad \widehat{\chi}(k)=\sum_{n=1}^q \chi(n) e^{-2i \pi nk/q}, \qquad \widehat{\chi}(q)=0$$
Whence 
$$f(0)= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{q} \sum_{k=1}^{q-1} \widehat{\chi}(k)  \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{e^{2i \pi nk/q}}{n} e^{-nx}=-\frac{1}{q} \sum_{k=1}^{q-1} \widehat{\chi}(k)  \lim_{x \to 0} \log(1-e^{-x+2i \pi k/q})\\= -\frac{1}{q} \sum_{k=1}^{q-1} \widehat{\chi}(k)   \log(1-e^{2i \pi k/q})
 $$

Iff $\chi$ is a primitive character then $$\widehat{\chi}(k) = \overline{\chi(k)} \ \widehat{\chi}(1), \qquad |\widehat{\chi}(1)|^2 = q$$